# Use segmented Control to reorder table

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` to query data from Parse, And I also have a segmented control on top. I want the user to be able to choose from reading latest feed or hottest feed. And below is my code

```
    var queryOrder = "createdAt"
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBAction func segmentedControlAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        queryOrder = "createdAt"
        queryForTable()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        queryOrder = "count"
        queryForTable()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Tucao")
    query.orderByDescending(queryOrder)
    query.limit = 100
    return query
}
```

the code kinda works, except that one have to pull to refresh the tableview in order to see the new result. How can I solve this?

Comment: Tapping your seg control updates the `queryOrder` param, but that doesn't mean `queryForTable` is getting called, or that whatever your datasource for the table is getting updated.

Comment: I added queryForTable() so that every time the segmentedControl was tapped, it will return a new query. But how can I make it update the table every time it is tapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to reloading the table's data, you have to fetch the latest objects from Parse using [`loadObjects`](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/loadObjects), ex:

```
self.loadObjects()
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

**Update in response to your update:** 
You shouldn't directly call `queryForTable()` in that way. Use `loadObjects()`.